# Unable to install anything

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I wonder if someone can help me ,

when I try install or remove a package , this is the error I get

```
dpkg: error processing package libdrm-nouveau2:i386 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgl1-mesa-dri:i386:
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 depends on libdrm-nouveau2 (>= 2.4.38); however:
  Package libdrm-nouveau2:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I try remove the package I get this error :

```
sudo apt-get remove libdrm-nouveau2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 account-plugin-facebook : Depends: libaccount-plugin-generic-oauth but it is not going to be installed or
                                    ubuntu-system-settings-online-accounts but it is not going to be installed
 indicator-bluetooth : Depends: unity-control-center but it is not going to be installed or
                                gnome-control-center but it is not going to be installed or
                                ubuntu-system-settings but it is not going to be installed
 indicator-network : Depends: unity8 (>= 7.82) but it is not going to be installed
 libegl1-mesa : Depends: libgbm1 (>= 7.11~1) but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: libegl1-mesa-drivers
 libmirserver18 : Depends: libmirplatformgraphics-mesa (= 0.1.8+14.04.20140411-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed or
                           libmirplatformgraphics-android (= 0.1.8+14.04.20140411-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt5gui5 : Depends: libgbm1 (>= 8.1~0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Comment: Can you please add some formatting to this to make it readable or perhaps pastebin this post?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the point of removing these packages?

Comment: Wouldn't you just need to reconfigure the package to correct it?  `sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdrm-nouveau2:i386`

Comment: sorry guys , Im not that good with this stuff, basically any program I try install through terminal or ubuntu software centre , it always fails

Answer (score 1):

According to Ubuntu Community Help Wiki, try running:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

From [the help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto),

> This command does the same thing as Edit->Fix Broken Packages in
>   Synaptic. Do this if you get complaints about packages with "unmet
>   dependencies".

Then if you still experience problems, run `sudo apt-get check` and report back.